# How can I make a recovery partition using my Windows 7 Installation disk?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, installation, compact-disc

Similar to how HP or ACER will create a partition on the hard drive which you can boot from using F10 or something similar if your computer crashes. What do I have to do to my windows 7 installation CD to make this partition act exactly as the CD does. I want there to be some way so that when I click F10, the recovery partition will start up and act as if I just put in the Windows 7 installation CD, but if I don't activate the partition, it will act as if it is not there. Do I need to download some sort of software to accomplish this, or would it be at all possible to just copy the files directly from the CD to the D:\ drive?

Comment: See this...http://www.suite101.com/content/how-to-create-a-windows-7-recovery-partition-a311149

Comment: Also this one...http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/21978-Windows-7-OEM-Recovery-Partition-tools-creator-Free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Rollback RX](http://www.horizondatasys.com/169614.ihtml) it is similar but much better than the HP, Acer restore systems in many ways.

Answer (score -1):

If you copy the files to the partition and set it as bootable, it should work. I think an even better solution: make the partition, then take the 30 minutes to install windows 7 from the CD to that partition. Then if you're forced to recover, you can skip that chore and go straight to windows.

As for setting the partition to an F key, I think that's written into the bios and cannot be changed/added/removed.

I did see this longwinded post that implies you can restore a norton ghost image using a built in key like F10. But it's old, not sure if this would still work. An image is ideal, you can restore without reinstalling anything.

http://www.911cd.net/forums//index.php?showtopic=12447&mode=linear

Comment: "As for setting the partition to an F key, I think that's written into the bios and cannot be changed/added/removed.".... Its part of the master boot record, not the bios in most cases, UEFI bios does play a part if it is configured to, mostly relies on the MBR.