# Setup custom recovery partition?

Tags: windows, partitioning, windows-installation

So My 12 year old brother is becoming an "I-know-everything" PC gamer. Hence he often jacks his computer up. Share-ware, Mal-ware, 8 million start up programs, you know the norm.

I'm going to do a fresh install on a new and bigger hard disk, and I want to setup a custom recovery partition. Something that will let me restore to factory default, but that he cannot delete or infect. The standard Dell/HP utility would be perfect.

Comment: I posted a SU link that may help, but that is also so close to your question that I feel it is a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you can install Dell/HP recovery apps on a computer that is not bought from them because of OEM licensing restrictions. But you can use standard windows backup/restore options to create windows system image (after installing everything required, but before installing any games or any funky software) at some safe location (say external USB drive) and use that image whenever you want to restore your brother's PC to initial setup.

If you don't like Windows' default backup/recovery options then you can try other [non windows backup/recovery tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_backup_software) too.

Answer (score 2):

Approximately 15 years ago, I decided a similar problem. We had to hide in a stationary workstation sections of different systems from each other. And also take into account the ability to see all the sections. At that time, I helped BootStar.

Was set the default login and password set to boot from the other sections. Consult the documentation. Although the imaging system has not been canceled.

Pdf : [Star-Tools BootStar Manual](http://www.star-tools.com/english/bootstar/manual.pdf)

[Star-Tools BootStar Downloads page](http://www.star-tools.com/english/downloads.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You also should do a search here in Super User as there are some similar questions, but a link to one that may help is [How can I make a recovery partition using my Windows 7 Installation disk?](https://superuser.com/questions/262973/how-can-i-make-a-recovery-partition-using-my-windows-7-installation-disk)

Look at some of the links in the comments from moab in that link.

Comment: Even though this has been closed, just a note: links to previous answers do not by themselves constitute valid answers and should be posted as comments instead.

Comment: @Karan Good point. Just wanted to give inside SU solution as I knw this was going to get closed. I'll keep your suggestion in mind.